# Out of index exception

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

Sorry if there is a simple solution to this, been trying to figure it out for a few hours, i can't seem to find the problem to the code, what could be wrong with it?

```
 public static void ShortestPath(int[,] waypoint, int source, int verticesCount) 
        {
            source = 0;
            waypoint = new int[verticesCount, verticesCount];
            int[] distance = new int[verticesCount];
            int[] previous = new int[verticesCount];
            PriorityQueue<int> priorityqueue = new PriorityQueue<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < verticesCount; i++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < verticesCount; l++)
                {
                    if (waypoint[i, l] != 0)
                    {
                        priorityqueue.Enqueue(i, waypoint[i, l]);
                    }
                }
            }

            while (!priorityqueue.empty() || priorityqueue != null)
            {
                int o = priorityqueue.dequeue_min();

                for (int v = 0; v < verticesCount; ++v)
                {
                    previous[v] = 0;
                    MinimumDistance(distance, verticesCount);     
                    if (waypoint[o, v] != 0)
                    {
                        if (distance[o] + waypoint[o, v] < distance[v])
                            distance[v] = distance[o] + waypoint[o, v];
                        previous[v] = o;
                        priorityqueue.Enqueue(o, distance[v]);

                    }
                      Print(distance[], verticesCount);
                }
            }
```

Comment: When you step through, where does the exception get thrown from?

Comment: In which line the error occurs?

Comment: Post the actual error please.

Comment: Also, where's the PriorityQueue class implementation?

Comment: Did you know that you can ask an array how big it is?  I'd bet that the dimensions of your waypoint array aren't verticesCount

Comment: Why does your method accept waypoint and source if you are immediately changing their values?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is with the `if` in your `while` loop where you are using `++v` instead of `v++`.

Code should be:

```
...
for (int v = 0; v < verticesCount; v++)
...
```